# Input to table one to many JPA with existing References Key

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have problem with my program.
I have 2 table with one to many relation.

In one record in table "A" which be references key in table "B";

How i can input record in table "B".
Thanks

Model for table A

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "muatan_ktsp", catalog = "bansm", schema = "public")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MuatanKtsp.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MuatanKtsp m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MuatanKtsp.findByMuatanKtspDate", query = "SELECT m FROM MuatanKtsp m WHERE m.muatanKtspDate = :muatanKtspDate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MuatanKtsp.findByMuatanKtspTime", query = "SELECT m FROM MuatanKtsp m WHERE m.muatanKtspTime = :muatanKtspTime"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MuatanKtsp.findByOrderDateDESC", query = "SELECT m FROM MuatanKtsp m ORDER BY m.muatanKtspDate DESC")})
public class MuatanKtsp implements Serializable {

    @Column(name =     "muatan_ktsp_date",insertable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date muatanKtspDate;
    @Column(name =     "muatan_ktsp_time",insertable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date muatanKtspTime;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<Penjurusan> penjurusanCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<PengaturanBebanBelajar> pengaturanBebanBelajarCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<PendidikanKecakapanHidup> pendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<PendidikanGlobalLokal> pendidikanGlobalLokalCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<MuatanLokal> muatanLokalCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<MataPelajaran> mataPelajaranCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<KriteriaKenaikanKelas> kriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<KriteriaKelulusan> kriteriaKelulusanCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "muatanKtspId")
    private List<KegiatanPengembanganDiri> kegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "muatan_ktsp_id", unique = true)
    private String muatanKtspId;

    public MuatanKtsp() {
    }

    public MuatanKtsp(String muatanKtspId) {
        this.muatanKtspId = muatanKtspId;
    }

    public Object getMuatanKtspId() {
        return muatanKtspId;
    }

    public void setMuatanKtspId(String muatanKtspId) {
        this.muatanKtspId = muatanKtspId;
    }

    public Date getMuatanKtspDate() {
        return muatanKtspDate;
    }

    public void setMuatanKtspDate(Date muatanKtspDate) {
        this.muatanKtspDate = muatanKtspDate;
    }

    public Date getMuatanKtspTime() {
        return muatanKtspTime;
    }

    public void setMuatanKtspTime(Date muatanKtspTime) {
        this.muatanKtspTime = muatanKtspTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (muatanKtspId != null ? muatanKtspId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof MuatanKtsp)) {
            return false;
        }
        MuatanKtsp other = (MuatanKtsp) object;
        if ((this.muatanKtspId == null && other.muatanKtspId != null) || (this.muatanKtspId != null && !this.muatanKtspId.equals(other.muatanKtspId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "bansm.model.MuatanKtsp[ muatanKtspId=" + muatanKtspId + " ]";
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<KegiatanPengembanganDiri> getKegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection() {
        return kegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection;
    }

    public void setKegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection(List<KegiatanPengembanganDiri> kegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection) {
        this.kegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection = kegiatanPengembanganDiriCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<KriteriaKelulusan> getKriteriaKelulusanCollection() {
        return kriteriaKelulusanCollection;
    }

    public void setKriteriaKelulusanCollection(List<KriteriaKelulusan> kriteriaKelulusanCollection) {
        this.kriteriaKelulusanCollection = kriteriaKelulusanCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<KriteriaKenaikanKelas> getKriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection() {
        return kriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection;
    }

    public void setKriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection(List<KriteriaKenaikanKelas> kriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection) {
        this.kriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection = kriteriaKenaikanKelasCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<MataPelajaran> getMataPelajaranCollection() {
        return mataPelajaranCollection;
    }

    public void setMataPelajaranCollection(List<MataPelajaran> mataPelajaranCollection) {
        this.mataPelajaranCollection = mataPelajaranCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<MuatanLokal> getMuatanLokalCollection() {
        return muatanLokalCollection;
    }

    public void setMuatanLokalCollection(List<MuatanLokal> muatanLokalCollection) {
        this.muatanLokalCollection = muatanLokalCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<PendidikanGlobalLokal> getPendidikanGlobalLokalCollection() {
        return pendidikanGlobalLokalCollection;
    }

    public void setPendidikanGlobalLokalCollection(List<PendidikanGlobalLokal> pendidikanGlobalLokalCollection) {
        this.pendidikanGlobalLokalCollection = pendidikanGlobalLokalCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<PendidikanKecakapanHidup> getPendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection() {
        return pendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection;
    }

    public void setPendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection(List<PendidikanKecakapanHidup> pendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection) {
        this.pendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection = pendidikanKecakapanHidupCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<PengaturanBebanBelajar> getPengaturanBebanBelajarCollection() {
        return pengaturanBebanBelajarCollection;
    }

    public void setPengaturanBebanBelajarCollection(List<PengaturanBebanBelajar> pengaturanBebanBelajarCollection) {
        this.pengaturanBebanBelajarCollection = pengaturanBebanBelajarCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Penjurusan> getPenjurusanCollection() {
        return penjurusanCollection;
    }

    public void setPenjurusanCollection(List<Penjurusan> penjurusanCollection) {
        this.penjurusanCollection = penjurusanCollection;
    }
```

Model for table B

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "mata_pelajaran", catalog = "bansm", schema = "public")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MataPelajaran.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MataPelajaran m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MataPelajaran.findByMataPelajaran", query = "SELECT m FROM MataPelajaran m WHERE m.mataPelajaran = :mataPelajaran"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MataPelajaran.findByKkm", query = "SELECT m FROM MataPelajaran m WHERE m.kkm = :kkm"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MataPelajaran.findByMataPelajaranId", query = "SELECT m FROM MataPelajaran m WHERE m.mataPelajaranId = :mataPelajaranId")})
public class MataPelajaran implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "mata_pelajaran")
    private String mataPelajaran;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "kkm", precision = 17, scale = 17)
    private Double kkm;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "mata_pelajaran_id", unique=true)
    private String mataPelajaranId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "muatan_ktsp_id", referencedColumnName = "muatan_ktsp_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private MuatanKtsp muatanKtspId;

    public MataPelajaran() {
    }

    public MataPelajaran(String mataPelajaranId) {
        this.mataPelajaranId = mataPelajaranId;
    }

    public MataPelajaran(String mataPelajaranId, String mataPelajaran) {
        this.mataPelajaranId = mataPelajaranId;
        this.mataPelajaran = mataPelajaran;
    }

    public String getMataPelajaran() {
        return mataPelajaran;
    }

    public void setMataPelajaran(String mataPelajaran) {
        this.mataPelajaran = mataPelajaran;
    }

    public Double getKkm() {
        return kkm;
    }

    public void setKkm(Double kkm) {
        this.kkm = kkm;
    }

    public String getMataPelajaranId() {
        return mataPelajaranId;
    }

    public void setMataPelajaranId(String mataPelajaranId) {
        this.mataPelajaranId = mataPelajaranId;
    }

    public MuatanKtsp getMuatanKtspId() {
        return muatanKtspId;
    }

    public void setMuatanKtspId(MuatanKtsp muatanKtspId) {
        this.muatanKtspId = muatanKtspId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (mataPelajaranId != null ? mataPelajaranId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof MataPelajaran)) {
            return false;
        }
        MataPelajaran other = (MataPelajaran) object;
        if ((this.mataPelajaranId == null && other.mataPelajaranId != null) || (this.mataPelajaranId != null && !this.mataPelajaranId.equals(other.mataPelajaranId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "bansm.model.MataPelajaran[ mataPelajaranId=" + mataPelajaranId + " ]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should persist not owner side entity first and then persist owner side entity. According to your codes, you should persist MuatanKtsp entity first. See [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/one-to-many-bidirectional-mapping-in-jpa) example.It may be  reference for you.